# onwsignal web notification error

Tags: php, html, url, push-notification, onesignal

actually i am tring to get data from url which i already got but i can't able to insert data into the array please check values are dummy1 dummy2

```
Array ( [id] => 491 [headings] => ‘సౌందర్య లహరి’ ఎలా ఉంది అంటే..? [content] => శ్రీ వాసు దర్శకత్వం లో బెల... [userPic] => 682473.jpg ) JSON sent: {"app_id":"35fi6c27-5f39-4s9f-94db-79bf123g0f9","included_segments":["All"],"data":{"foo":"bar"},"contents":{"en":"dummy1"},"headings":{"en":"dummy2"},"url":"http:\/\/www.gggg.in\/view.php?id=[id]","chrome_web_image":"http:\/\/www.ggg.in\/admin\/user_images\/[userPic]"} JSON received: {"allresponses":"{\"id\":\"f66a03a4-1b17-8tf3-93ed-f3ad6rt7cdb9\",\"recipients\":6}"}
```

the above data got from url
http://www.ggg.in/gistfile1.php?id=491&headings=%E2%80%98%E0%B0%B8%E0%B1%8C%E0%B0%82%E0%B0%A6%E0%B0%B0%E0%B1%8D%E0%B0%AF%20%E0%B0%B2%E0%B0%B9%E0%B0%B0%E0%B0%BF%E2%80%99%20%E0%B0%8E%E0%B0%B2%E0%B0%BE%20%E0%B0%89%E0%B0%82%E0%B0%A6%E0%B0%BF%20%E0%B0%85%E0%B0%82%E0%B0%9F%E0%B1%87..?&content=%20%E0%B0%B6%E0%B1%8D%E0%B0%B0%E0%B1%80%20%E0%B0%B5%E0%B0%BE%E0%B0%B8%E0%B1%81%20%E0%B0%A6%E0%B0%B0%E0%B1%8D%E0%B0%B6%E0%B0%95%E0%B0%A4%E0%B1%8D%E0%B0%B5%E0%B0%82%20%E0%B0%B2%E0%B1%8B%20%E0%B0%AC%E0%B1%86%E0%B0%B2...&userPic=682473.jpg

and i need to insert the values in this function

```
function sendMessage() {
$content      = array(
    "en" => 'dummy1'
);
$headings   = array(
    "en" => 'dummy2'
);
$hashes_array = array();

$fields = array(
    'app_id' => "35fi6c27-5f39-4s9f-94db-79bf123g0f9",
    'included_segments' => array(
        'All'
    ),
    'data' => array(
        "foo" => "bar"
    ),
    'contents' => $content,
    'headings' => $headings,
    'url' => 'http://www.gggg.in/view.php?id=[id]',
    'chrome_web_image'  => 'http://www.ggg.in/admin/user_images/[userPic]',        

);
```

Answer (score 0):

OneSignal does not support substituting variable data directly into API calls. However, you can achieve this with Tag and Variable Substitution: https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/personalization

Comment: as you said OneSignal does not support substituting variable data directly into API calls.  that is wrong and just not i did it

Answer (score 0):

this is the solutions for this Question i asked about
actually i have a varable passing throug url and i need them to insert into function

```
$array = [
'id' => 498, 
'value2' => 'యూట్యూబ్‌లో “భరత్ అనే నేను” అన్ కట్ సీన్లు..!',
'value1' => 'కొరటాల శివ దర్శకత్వం లో సూ...',
'value3' => '525722.jpg'
];


sendMessage($array);

function sendMessage($array) {
    $content      = array(
        "en" => $array['value1']
        );
    $headings   = array(
        "en" => $array['value2']
        );
    $hashes_array = array();


$fields = array(
    'app_id' => "31pe2347-5i39-4y9f-2222-79b5875f00f9",
    'included_segments' => array(
        'All'
        ),
    'data' => array(
        "foo" => "bar"
        ),
    'contents' => $content,
    'headings' => $headings,
    'url' => 'http://w...content-available-to-author-only...9.in/view.php?id=' . $array['id'],
    'chrome_web_image'  => 'http://w...content-available-to-author-only...9.in/admin/user_images/' . $array['value3'],        

    );
print_r($fields);
```

}